# Storing character from a 1D array into a 2D array

Tags: c, arrays

I'm trying to move an item from a 1D array into a 2D array with this loop but it happen to infinite loop is somthing wrong hre..

```
printf("Enter plaintext :");
scanf("%s",&plaintext);



while(plaintext[k]!='\0')
{

    for (i=0;i<5;i++)
    {
        for (j=0;j<5;j++)
        {
        chip[i][j]=plaintext[k];
        k++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to use a debugger and put in a break point, trace it yourself. This is a key programming skill you need to learn.

Comment: Without knowing what row, coll, k, length, and c are, this is impossible to conclusively answer. Either provide more information or more code.

Comment: there isn't any error at least in this part of the code.

Comment: I'm confused by the combination of your code and your description.  It looks like you're copying the same element from `plaintext` into every element of the array, since nothing increments `k` unless it's NULL.  If `plaintext[k]` starts out non-NULL, I would expect that code to run forever.

Comment: how to say while  plain not empty keep do the loop

Comment: infinite loop? maybe there is missing \0 mark at end of string? although then it should crash at least...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    scanf("%s", plaintext);

    for (i=0;i<5;i++){
        for (j=0;j<5;j++){
            chip[i][j]=plaintext[k++];
            if(plaintext[k] == '\0'){
                i=j=5;//break;
            }
        }
    }
```

other way

```
    char *p;

    printf("Enter plaintext :");
    scanf("%s", plaintext);

    p=&chip[0][0];
    while(k < 25 && plaintext[k]!='\0'){
        *p++ = plaintext[k++];
    }
```

show chip

```
    for (i=0;i<5;i++){
        for (j=0;j<5;j++){
            putchar(chip[i][j]);
            if(--k == 0)
                i=j=5;//break;
        }
        putchar('\n');
    }
```

Comment: but still nothin in chip its stop working when im try to show chip

Answer (score 0):

The variable `k` will be incremented regardless of `if(plaintext[k]!=NULL)` and may cross the border. So instead of

```
if (plaintext[k] != NULL)
    chip[i][j] = plaintext[k];
else
    c = +1;
k++;
```

try

```
if (plaintext[k] != NULL)
    chip[i][j] = plaintext[k++];
else {
    c = +1;
    break;
}
```

Meanwhile, if `length` is longer than the size of the 2d array, characters copied in early iterations will be overwritten.